# Sailsjs not displaying model data associations in view

Tags: node.js, sails.js

Using Sails.js **v0.12.4** and Node.js **v6.4.0**.

I'm trying to display a *One to Many* association using MVC into a specific view.

**User.js**

```
module.exports = {
    attributes: {
        tickets: {
            collection: 'ticket',
            via: 'owner'
        }
    }
}
```

**Ticket.js**

```
module.exports = {
    attributes: {
        owner: {
            model: 'user'
        }
    }
}
```

**UserController.js**

```
show: function(req, res, next) {
    User.findOne(req.param('id')).exec(function(err, user) {
        if (err) next(err);
        if (!user) return next();
        res.view({
            user: user,
            userTickets: user.tickets
        });
    });
},
```

**/edit/user/show.ejs**

```
<% _.each(userTickets, function (ticket) { %>
<tr data-id="<%= ticket.id %>" data-model="ticket">
    <td> <%= ticket.id %> </td>
    <td> <%= ticket.ticketName %> </td>

    <td><a href="/ticket/show/<%= ticket.id %>">Show</a></td>
    <td><a href="/ticket/edit/<%= ticket.id %>">Edit</a></td>
    <td><a href="/ticket/destroy/<%= ticket.id %>">Delete</a></td>
</tr>
<% }) %>
```

I'm even finding the association in my MongoDB Database:

**A Ticket Object Belonging to: "57c1207dea46efef0c0cd27d"**

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("57c27f6de4c7fd2d036a96b5"),
"owner" : ObjectId("57c1207dea46efef0c0cd27d"),
"ticketName" : "asdfasdfasdfasdfasdf",
"createdAt" : ISODate("2016-08-28T06:06:37.085Z"),
"updatedAt" : ISODate("2016-08-28T06:06:37.085Z")
}
```

**The User Object**

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("57c1207dea46efef0c0cd27d"),
"firstName" : "Dan",
"lastName" : "Michaels",
"email" : "DM@nike.com",
"createdAt" : ISODate("2016-08-27T05:09:17.598Z"),
"updatedAt" : ISODate("2016-08-27T05:09:17.598Z")
}
```

It's not displaying anything in my /show.ejs page..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
User.findOne(req.param('id')).exec(function(err, user) {
```

to

```
User.findOne(req.param('id')).populate('tickets').exec(function(err, user) {
```

http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/queries/populate

That should do it.

Comment: I am forever in your debt<3